# I want to select mutiple columns in group by query

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

this is my TEAM table

```
POSITION NAME      HEIGHT
________ _________ ______
GK       Jhon      178
GK       Steven    190
DF       Paul      183   
DF       Andrew    178
DF       Nick      169
MF       Ali       170
MF       Peter     176
MF       Charlie   180
FW       Simon     185
FW       Son       184
FW       Jack      179
```

I want to select position, name and highest players each positions like:

```
POSITION NAME      HEIGHT
________ _________ ______
GK       Steven    190
DF       Paul      183
MF       Charlie   180
FW       Simon     185
```

Here is the code I tried.

```
SELECT POSITION, MAX(HEIGHT) FROM TEAM GROUP BY POSITION;
```

and that's the answer:

```
POSITION HEIGHT
________ ______
GK       190
DF       183
MF       180
FW       185
```

As a result, I hope to insert name column on that result.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a keep/last column expression:

```
MAX(NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY HEIGHT)
```

Giving:

```
SELECT POSITION,
  MAX(NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY HEIGHT) AS NAME,
  MAX(HEIGHT) AS HEIGHT
FROM TEAM
GROUP BY POSITION;
```

| POSITION | NAME | HEIGHT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DF | Paul | 183 |
| FW | Simon | 185 |
| GK | Steven | 190 |
| MF | Charlie | 180 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-WHP_i2y)

Comment: I haven't learned that query yet. It's very impressive thanks,Alex

Answer (score 1):

One canonical approach uses the `RANK()` analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY POSITION ORDER BY HEIGHT DESC) rnk
    FROM TEAM t
)

SELECT POSITION, NAME, HEIGHT
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```